# Outlook Calender Item - History of Acceptance

Tags: outlook

I would like to see when I accepted an Outlook Calendar Invite (Outlook item). I know that I have made two "Accept" clicks yesterday and one today for the same Calendar Invite. How can I find the timestamp for when I accepted these two invites for the same meeting?

I'm not sure if coding is required or if there is a view on Outlook that would have this information. So any and all suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be an `IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Pos` meeting item in your Sent Items folder. You can look at its date.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think it would be that easy. I was able to find all my "Accepted" statuses for each meeting by searching in my Send Items folder.